# CustomerKey property size limit of DataFolder Object

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I would like to ask if someone here knows what is the maximum size of `CustomerKey` property on `DataFolder` Object in Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SFMC interface caps External/Customer Key field entry at **36** characters, but I'm not sure it's documented anywhere for the API:

[image: Max External Key Length]

Comment: Thank you @adam. I tried to add longer `CustomerKey` with API but it adds just first 36 characters. It would be nice to have it documented somewhere.